# Structured typing in Scala doesn't work with Double?

Tags: scala

I'm trying to do the following code:

```
def sum(e: { def *(x: Double): Double}) = e * 2.0
```

Problem is, this doesn't work with any numeric classes:

```
sum(20.0)
<console>:9: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Double(10.0)
 required: AnyRef{def *(x: Double): Double}
              algo(10.0)

sum(10)
<console>:9: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int(10)
 required: AnyRef{def *(x: Double): Double}
              algo(10)
```

Is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: It seems the problem is that Double is value type (subtype of AnyVal). And scala structural typing want instance of reference type (AnyRef)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Scala's structural type doesn't require AnyRef.

Certainly, the following method declaration doesn't work as expected.

```
def sum(e: { def *(x: Double): Double }) = e * 2.0
```

The reason of that is the above code is interpreted as the followings:

```
def sum(e: AnyRef { def *(x: Double): Double}) = e * 2.0
```

If you specify Any explicitly, the code works:

```
scala> def sum(e: Any { def *(x: Double): Double }) = e * 2.0
sum: (e: Any{def *(x: Double): Double})Double

scala> sum(10.0)
res0: Double = 20.0
```

Comment: It's worth noting that this behavior is defined in section "3.2.7 Compound Types" of [the spec](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf): "A compound type may also consist of just a refinement `{R}` with no preceding component types. Such a type is equivalent to `AnyRef{R}`."

Answer (score 9):

Your `sum` method expects a subtype of [AnyRef](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/AnyRef.html) while [Double](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Double.html) and other numeric types are subtypes of [AnyVal](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/AnyVal.html). What you should do instead, is to use the [Numeric](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/math/Numeric.html) typeclass.

```
def sum[E:Numeric](e:E) = {
  val n = implicitly[Numeric[E]]
  n.toDouble(e) * 2
}
```